# Do you need an sks file for every device in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I was wondering if you need an sks file for every device so self.frame.size is the same size as the device your using. Like create one for iPhone 4,5,6,6+ and all the iPads. Also is their another way to get the screen size for all iOS devices. I tried several ways all already but it keeps on failing in the end except the iPhone 6+.

Comment: this question makes no sense.

Comment: It makes sense. Do you need and sks file for every device for its scene in swift or can you only have one. I am having troubles getting the screen size to be the exact height and it's always off except in the iPhone 6+